# smarty - how to use variables in code?

Tags: smarty

This is part of my smarty code:

```
{if $cat=="3_0" or $cat=="3_15" or $cat=="3_16" or $cat=="3_17"}
```

How can I setup my code to use variable for characters (numbers) 15, 16, 17...? For example I would like have short code like that:

```
{if $cat=="3_0" or $cat=="3_"+ any two characters}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can do something like:

```
{if $cat|substr:0:2 eq "3_"}
```

or

```
{if $cat|truncate:2 eq "3_"}
```

http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifiers.tpl

Let me know ;)

Comment: Only first way is working perfect for me. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome.
I was not sure about the second one. :)
Good luck!